# Need a shell script to automatically input 1-10000 into a program

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, unix

Pretty simple, I need to test a C program by inputting a large number of integers into it. To do this, for this particularly case, I need to run the program, then when it waits for user input (scanf("%d, integer)), I need to give it the integer from the loop I'm currently at.

right now I have

```
    for i in {1..5};
do 
(echo -n "$i" && ./a2 $i)
done
```

but it still just waits for user input, then after user input is given, prints the integer of the loop I'm on. I've tried a few examples from similar problems I've found on stack exchange and elsewhere but so far no luck. I haven't ever really needed to mess about with shell scripting before so it's probably something simple I'm doing backasswordsly but no one else has done wrong before.

Comment: Maybe: `seq 1 10000 | ./a2` is what you're after?  This runs the program once and feeds it the numbers 1 to 10000 on its standard input.  It will get EOF after it reads 10000.  But maybe if you just need the numbers 1 to 10000 you should have the program process a pair of command line arguments and generate the numbers itself?

Comment: There's a difference between command line arguments and standard input.

Comment: Try `|` instead of `&&`. (Note: in shell scripts, `|` is *not* OR, but something entirely different)

Comment: Do you want to run your program once with 10000 input numbers, or 10000 times with 1 input number each?

Comment: process substitution will allow elimination of the pipe `./a2 < <(seq 1 10000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this!

```
for i in `seq 1 1000`; do echo $i | ./a2; done
```

Your solution

```
echo -n "$i" && ./a2 $i
```

would pass $i as argument for a2 not input.

Comment: Well, since it is bash, a simple `./a2 < <(seq 1 10000)` would do. (*note:* the `space` between `< <`.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is not usually done using shell script.

You can write a `c code` to generate your input, which in this case is numbers from 1-10000. Let that file be testGenerator.c. Then, run this on your terminal:

```
gcc testGenerator.c
./a.out >input
```

This will create a file, named `input` which will have numbers from 1 to 10000, which is of course the o/p of testGenerator.c.

Then, if your program, in which you want input is compiled into `a2`, as I can see, you can run it as:

```
./a2 <input >output
```

and you will get the required output in the file `output`. If you don't write `>output` here, you will see o/p on terminal.

Also, when you are running this script, you are actually running the `a2` 10000 times and giving a number as command line argument, which is very different from taking input from `stdin` which of course, `scanf` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..1000}; do echo $i | ./a2; done
```